# Has the value of DateTimeFormatInfo::AbbreviatedDayNames ever changed across .Net framework versions for Spain?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
var thursday = new CultureInfo("es-ES").DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames[4];
```

which returns "ju.", as expected.

I have just inherited some pretty old code, which has test code that expects the value to be "jue"...

I was wondering - has this ever changed in the .Net framework?

EDIT 1 - To extend:

I am using .Net 4.5... I have a recently built machine with Visual Studio 2013 and nothing out of the ordinary installed.

```
        var format = new CultureInfo("es-ES").DateTimeFormat;

        Console.WriteLine("AbbreviatedDayNames:");

        foreach (var name in format.AbbreviatedDayNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("ShortestDayNames:");

        foreach (var name in format.ShortestDayNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
```

Outputs:

```
AbbreviatedDayNames:
do.
lu.
ma.
mi.
ju.
vi.
sá.
ShortestDayNames:
D
L
M
X
J
V
S
```

Edit 2 - My machine is UK english, although I don't see why that would matter if I specify the culture as "es-ES"?

Edit 3 - Weirdly:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/
 - returns ju.

http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php
 - returns jue

Comment: It returns `jue` on me. What is your .NET Framework version? I use .NET Framework 4.5. Are you sure you don't mix it with `ShortestDayNames`? Because it has `ju`.

Comment: Returning `jue` for me in .NET Framework 2, 3, 3.5 and 4.5.

Comment: Returns `jue` for in 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4 either.

Comment: Curiously, it returns `ju.` for me on 4.5. This is also the case on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SHN1CM).

Comment: So what're the localization settings on the machines in question?

Comment: Another test case, jue, for me on 4.0 Client Profile, although one would hope that doesn't matter

Comment: I think it uses a native API to get the names (possibly EnumCalendarInfoEx).  In which case differences will probably depend on the OS version rather than the framework version.  My Windows 7 64 bit + .NET 4.0 returns "jue".

Comment: My computer is configured in Spanish(Argentina), and I get this with your code:

AbbreviatedDayNames:
dom
lun
mar
mié
jue
vie
sáb
ShortestDayNames:
do
lu
ma
mi
ju
vi
sá

Comment: Note that `www.compileonline.com` uses [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)) and probably runs on a non-Windows operating system.

Answer (score 1):

The CalendarData object makes a C# to C++ transition when fetching the calendar data, on its way to acquiring calendar information from the OS.

OS version and settings differences for the values in the array would be the cause of this, not an actual .NetFX change.

You can reference the C# framework code at http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Globalization/CalendarData@cs/1305376/CalendarData@cs and note the managed-to-native included method.

Comment: Sounds likely. Do you know what the OS differences could be? - I'm running Windows 8.1 latest by the way...

Comment: It appears that compileonline.com is running on a linux flavor using Mono; dotnetfiddle.net seems to be an Azure instance. A quick experiment with some different VMs could be informative.